# What is the best way to set relations of fixed objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Hi I have two kind of objects(a,b) in my seed file and I want to set relation a Has_many b and b belongs_to a between them. How can I do this?

My idea is to create them as function in seed and after they are created, update b a_id references as a function still in seed file.

Question is there any more Ruby way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = A.create
a.bs.create(b_params)
```